# JavaScript regular expression exception (Invalid group)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
/(?<={index:)\d+(?=})/g
```

I am trying to find index integer in strings like this one:

```
some text{index:1}{id:2}{value:3}
```

That expression works fine with php, but it doesn't work in javascript, I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular
>   expression: /(?<={index:)\d+(?=})/:
>   Invalid group

What do I need to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: try escaping your curly-brackets.

Comment: @jnpcl I just tried it a minute ago `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=\{index:)\d+(?=\})/: Invalid group` it doesn't work, unless there is another way to escape curly brackets other than `\{`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`(?<= )` is a positive lookbehind. JavaScript's flavor of RegEx does not support lookbehinds (but it does support lookaheads).

Comment: Actually, looks like lookbehinds are officially part of the JS Regex spec (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#assertions), but only supported in Chromium as of posting (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: How can it be replaced and get the same behavior?

Comment: If nothing else works, you could reverse the string, do a reversed regexp match with a positive lookahead and reverse the result. But that may not apply to your problem you're having.

Answer (score 11):

JavaScript does not support look-behind assertions.  Use this pattern instead:

```
/{index:(\d+)}/g
```

Then extract the value captured in the group.

Comment: it extracts the whole thing, in my case I just need an integer.

Comment: @negative: Notice the parentheses around the `\d+`; the integer is captured in group #1.

Comment: @Alan Moore, may be I am doing something wrong, but `"some text{index:1}{id:2}{value:3}".match(/{index:(\d+)}/g)[0]` returns `{index:1}` AND `"some text{index:1}{id:2}{value:3}".match(/{index:(\d+)}/g)[1]` returns 'undefined'.

Answer (score 5):

```
var str = "some text{index:1}{id:2}{value:3}";
var index = str.match(/{index:(\d+)}/);
index = index && index[1]*1;
```

Comment: Ah, I see, no `/g` really helps =)