# Regex - unhandled js exception in react native

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

I am using the following regex in my react-native app.

This is an email validation regex :

```
^[\w]+@((?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+)(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]{2,63}(?<!-))
```

This works fine in the browser but crashes the react native app due to the following :

[no stack', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56990784/no-stack-reason-unhandled-js-exception-invalid-regular-expression-invalid)

Could someone please help getting this to work on react native, maybe by achieving the same thing that this regex achieves but without the lookbehind expression ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no stack', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56990784/no-stack-reason-unhandled-js-exception-invalid-regular-expression-invalid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely caused the by the `(?<!-)` negative lookahead at the end of the regex pattern, which your JavaScript engine does not support.  To ensure that a hyphen does not occur at the end of the email, we can simply use:

```regex
^[\w]+@((?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+)(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,62}[A-Za-z0-9])
```

That is, just use `[A-Za-z0-9]` to represent the final of 63 possible characters in the pattern.

Comment: The issue with this regex (which the original regex accounts for), is the following cases are not matched :

somethiing@g.co
something@co.uk
something@c.co.uk
somethign@com.co.uk

Comment: My answer should be logically _equivalent_ to what you have above, and it should fully address the incompatibility issue.  If you have some _other_ issue with your current regex, you might want to open a new question.

Comment: Can you please explain how it is logically equivalent if the original regex matched certain emails that the new regex you provided isn't ?

Comment: @user3055126 You were right, I had a problem.  Please try the update above.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will not work likely problem in regex pattern i think.

> this works for me for simple email format abc@mail.com

```
var regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```