# How to solve Invalid regular expression error when running app in android in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-native

I am running an android app in React native. Since I use regex when I run the app Invalid regular expression: Invalid group specifier name
I get an error saying no stack.

Looking for a problem, it say this is look behind problem.

then how can i change my regex?

this is my regex

```
let regex = /^\.|\.$|(?<=\..*)\.|[^\d.]/g;
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: what does `change the value of the sharedBlacklist array` have to do with supposedly invalid regex (which seems to be a valid regular expression) - unless it needs to be a valid Java regex (because of the native part of react-native) - then, you'll need to change the regex to be valid Java regex?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56990784/no-stack-reason-unhandled-js-exception-invalid-regular-expression-invalid I think that version of android does not support negative look behinds in regular expressions.

Comment: @AlexWayne How can i chage regex instead of  my regex?